# how to resolve "illegal instruction error" when I am trying to import cv2 in my code for face recognition

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition

When I am trying to import `opencv`, `matplotlib`, `numpy`, etc, for my face recognition code in python and the terminal is showing:

> illegal instruction

I tried reinstalling the opencv dependencies, reinstalled python ide, tried to clear cache memory but nothing worked.

Comment: Supply complete error messages.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.